# Organizing data into multiple columns SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, dbeaver

I have a table of more than 5m customers with historic activity data as in example below:

| Customer ID | PART_ID | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 202012 | 2 |
| 12345 | 202101 | 0 |
| 12345 | 202102 | 5 |

I want to convert this data into multiple columns; customers at the rows, dates in the columns and their respective activity info.

I wrote the code below but instead of creating a single row for a single customer, customers duplicate and I get a table like this:

| Customer ID | 202012 | 202101 | 202102 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 12345 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12345 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Instead of:

| Customer ID | 202012 | 202101 | 202102 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT CUST_ID, RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202012 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ARA_20,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202101 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OCA_21,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202102 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SUB_21,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202103 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MAR_21,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202104 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NIS_21,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202105 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MAY_21,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202106 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HAZ_21,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202107 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TEM_21,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202108 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AGU_21,
      CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202109 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EYL_21
    FROM ACTIVITY
    WHERE RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER IN (108, 103, 170)
    GROUP BY CUST_ID, RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER
)
WHERE ARA_20 + OCA_21 + SUB_21 + MAR_21 + NIS_21 + MAY_21 +
      HAZ_21 + TEM_21 + AGU_21 + EYL_21 > 0
```

Comment: You're grouping by two things, `CUST_ID` and `RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER`, so you'll get multiple columns per customer. What is `RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER`?

Comment: RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER is specific to a customer and a customer can only have a single value for it. you can just as well remove it from the query.

Comment: SUM / COUNT / MAX  aggregation is missing. For example `MAX (CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202012 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ARA_20`

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm using DBeaver DMBS, also added as a tag.

Comment: Your query does not match the output. Your output should have the columns CUST_ID, RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER, ARA_20, OCA_21, and so on. Also, the table is called ACTIVITY and it has a column called ACTIVITY?

Comment: DBeaver is not a database. It is a tool for working with databases. We need to know your database *server*. SQL Server? Postgres? MySQL? SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    WHERE RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER IN (108, 103, 170)
    GROUP BY CUST_ID, RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER
```

You're grouping by two values, the customer and RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER. RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER can have three possible values, so you're going to get up to three rows per customer. If you want only one row per customer, remove RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER from your group by.

It's possible you added RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER to the group by because the query didn't work without it. If you want to include RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER in your select, but not your group by, you need to aggregate RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER as well. Even if each customer only has one value for it. Use [`string_agg`](https://www.sqlshack.com/string_agg-function-in-sql/).

```
SELECT CUST_ID, string_agg(RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER, ', ')
```

If a customer has only one value for RULLED_PROFIT_CENTER you'll get just that one value.

---

Since you're grouping all the rows of a customer together, you will need to take the `max` of your activities.

```
MAX( CASE WHEN PART_ID = 202012 AND ACTIVITY > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ARA_20
```

Comment: while string_agg did not work as a function, adding max to case when solved the problem. Thanks!